# split table over two pages, new width for each page

Tags: longtable, xtab

I saw someone answered this.  Apparently you need to use \xtab, but I can't figure out how to adapt it to this longtable.  I basically want the table to center as best as possible on each page.  Thank you.

```
\documentclass[A4paper, 10pt, openany, draft]{book}

%PACKAGES
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.83in, paperheight=8.27in, bindingoffset=.625in]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{\fancyhead{}\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}}

\begin{document}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries\centering\Large}{}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\normalfont\itshape\centering}{}{0pt}{}

\chapter{Chapter Title}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\textsc{First List}}
\thispagestyle{firststyle}

\setlength\LTleft{\fill}
\setlength\LTright{\fill}
\begin{longtable}{r l}

1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
1: & desc 1\\
7: & descriptiondescription 4325985\\
7: & descriptiondescription 4325985\\
7: & descriptiondescription 4325985\\
7: & descriptiondescription 4325985\\


\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The purpose of `longtable` is to make equal columns across pages.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I thought there might be some way to adapt the longtable , but I guess I should just re-do the table using the other package.